# Can a Filipino citizen with US green card exit Shanghai for a layover?

Tags: filipino-citizens, shanghai

I have a 12 hr layover in Shanghai but I am not sure if I can go around and see some sites in Shanghai. Does anyone know if I am qualified to get the TWOV in Shanghai for 24 hrs?

Tahnks